ThinkPad T480 stuck on 'To interrupt normal startup, press Enter' screen – tried multiple fixes, still no luck. Any advice?
My ThinkPad T480 is stuck on the startup screen displaying the Lenovo logo and the message 'To interrupt normal startup, press Enter.' I can access the BIOS settings, but none of the following troubleshooting steps have worked:
Hard shutdown
Pressing the small reset button with a pin
Removing the battery and all cables
Changing boot order in BIOS
I'm still stuck at the same screen every time I start up the laptop. Any advice on what else I can try to resolve this issue?
